# Is there a way to programmatically retrieve the connected UA property ID for GA4?

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

I have a list of UA properties that have been converted to GA4. Is there a way to obtain the GA4 ID for each of them? That information is available in the analytics UI.

[image: UI connected property]

There is no such attribute in the [GA4 property object](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/get) and in the [UA WebProperty object](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/get).